# Hovering UITableViewController over a UIViewController on iPhone not displaying cell content (e.g. FB notification view)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, hover, uitableview

I am trying to create a hovering UITableViewController over a UIViewController. I have managed to open the TableView over the ViewController. ([Picture](http://zikerler.com/SO/hover.png))

When first loading the view the data is loaded and I can see the rows for split second, but then it disappears. I understand that I must be assigning something over the actual view in the memory. However I can't fins what I am doing wrong.

Here is how I try to do it:

**I create it as a object and load it with animation**

```
BINotificationView *notifView = [[BINotificationView alloc] init];

notifView.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400);

[notifView.tableView setDataSource:notifView];
[notifView.tableView setDelegate:notifView];
[notifView setResultSet:_notifSet];

notifView.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[self.view addSubview:notifView.view];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
[notifView.view setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
```

**When view is loaded the tableview is populated (with same cell identifier in storyboard)**

```
@interface BINotificationView ()

@end

@implementation BINotificationView

@synthesize resultSet;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.alpha = 0.0;
    self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (resultSet.count) {
        return resultSet.count;
    }
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"notif";
    NotificationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[NotificationCell alloc] init];
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 80);
    }

    cell.notification = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 80)];
    [cell addSubview:cell.notification];

    [cell.notification setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNextCondensed-Regular" size:16]];

    if (resultSet.count) {
        BINotification *obj = [resultSet objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.notification.text = obj.type;
    }

    else {
        cell.notification.text = @"Empty List";
    }

    [cell.notification setEditable:NO];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 80.0;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

**My UITableViewCell is defined as**

```
@interface NotificationCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *notification;

@end

@implementation NotificationCell

@synthesize notification;

@end
```

**The UITableViewController .h file is like this**

```
@interface BINotificationView : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *resultSet;

@end
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: self.view.alpha = 0.0 ?

Comment: Yes it starts with alpha=0.0 then using the animation in the first piece of code I gave I set it to 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like notifView is released when its scope ends. But its view is added as a subview, this may explain why it is seen for a while. The solution is to extend the scope of notifView, try making it a property of the controller which adds notifView's view as a subview.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! I thought it passed its scope to the subviews array

Answer (score 0):

```
 notification = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 80)];
    [self addSubview:notification];
```

Add this in your UITableViewCell file

Comment: Just to be clear should I add this to the `init` of the UITableViewCell class? (i.e. NotificationCell)

Comment: And sorry still the same problem exists, the data is displayed only for a blink of the eye

Comment: Can you please post the tableview delegate methods here?

Comment: There are no delegate function used yet, I am only trying to see the content longer than a blink. The only three functions used in the UITableViewController (BINotificationView) are already posted in my question, but let me post the entire class rather parts of it.

Comment: [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0];
Comment out this line

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but that was one of the things I already tried.. I used some breakpoints to verify that everything is called properly, and it is.. I believe the problem is a memory issue and the view is somehow overwritten after it is being created hence the values in the NSMutableArray are lost..